# How to add frontmatter fields to an existing Markdown file in TinaCMS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I’m wondering if it is possible to edit a Markdown file with TinaCMS by adding new frontmatter fields. I’m not interested in creating a completely new Markdown file, but rather editing the existing one by adding new frontmatter fields. Right now I can edit a single field, but I can’t add a new field on top of it. The reason for this is because I have a navbar menu where every menu item is a frontmatter property. I want to be able to extend my navbar menu by adding a new property. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through posting the same question on the TinaCMS community forum. By using the fields "group-list", it is completely possible to add, and remove frontmatter fields from TinaCMS. More information can be found here: https://tinacms.org/docs/fields/blocks